# NSIS problem accessing data

Tags: qt, nsis

I'll try to make myself as clear as possible.

I made an installation program with NSIS. An icon was created on the desktop and when I double-click it, the application lanches well.
However, in the install directory I have other directories (like "css" which contains "style.css"), and it seems that the program is looking for my css file in the directory of the shortcut (-> desktop).

How could I make the program looking in the install directory rather than in the desktop ?

Thanks for your answers.

---

Here is the code I used :

```
Section "Shortcuts"
SectionIn 2 
SetOutPath "$SMPROGRAMS\MyApp"
CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\MyApp\MyApp.lnk" "$INSTDIR\MyApp.exe"
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
CreateShortCut "$DESKTOP\MyApp.lnk" "$INSTDIR\MyApp.exe"
SectionEnd
```

If I change the outpath (line 3) to "$INSTDIR", the shortcut isn't created at all. If I use this code, the shortcut is created but the "start in" parameter is set to the desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in this case is that your application is using relative paths without qualifying them; the simple solution is to have the shortcut specify the working directory: (it seems strange that the `SetOutPath` alters the `CreateShortCut`, but the manual says it does)

```
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
CreateShortCut "$DESKTOP\MyApp.lnk" "$INSTDIR\MyApp.exe" # etc.
```

The proper solution is to make all paths absolute; you've tagged it as `qt` so I presume you're using Qt and C++. Search around for "qt absolute path" and things like that - e.g. [Qt-interest Archive - How to get an application's absolute path?](http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2005-01/thread00043-0.html)

Comment: Thanks, I found this solution too, but there's another problem now : 
CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\MyApp\MyApp.lnk" "$INSTDIR\MyApp.exe" create the shortcut in the program list, but I have the same problem than before, except that this time SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
doesn't change anything... Any idea ?

Comment: Another problem now? What problem? If it's things going in the wrong places after that, use `SetOutPath` again to go back to where it was.

Comment: Sorry I pressed "enter" too fast, I didn't finish the post ;)

Comment: That *should* work... would you mind providing more code for context in the question? Might be something too obvious to see which might be apparent when I look at it.  Or it might be some confusing behaviour generally.

Answer (score 0):

```
Section "Shortcuts"
SectionIn 2 
CreateDirectory "$SMPROGRAMS\MyApp" #CreateShortCut does not create directories
SetOutPath "INSTDIR"
CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\MyApp\MyApp.lnk" "$INSTDIR\MyApp.exe"
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
CreateShortCut "$DESKTOP\MyApp.lnk" "$INSTDIR\MyApp.exe"
SectionEnd
```